# Filter JSON API response based on name

Tags: python, json, api

I've gotten through many other similar questions / threads but none could help me.
So I have this api response which gives me a list of jobs that ran on a vm.
I want to summarize the runtime of a specific job named 'Release Name': 'Data Scraping'

```
"value": [
    {
        "EndTime": "2021-02-03T05:25:00.643Z",
        "Info": "Job completed",
        "JobPriority": "Normal",
        "ReleaseName": "Data scraping",
        "RuntimeType": "Unattended",
        "StartTime": "2021-02-03T05:00:07.183Z",
    },
    {
        "EndTime": "2021-02-03T05:25:00.643Z",
        "Info": "Job completed",
        "JobPriority": "Normal",
        "ReleaseName": "Data scraping",
        "RuntimeType": "Unattended",
        "StartTime": "2021-02-03T05:00:07.183Z",
    },
    {
        "EndTime": "2021-02-03T05:25:00.643Z",
        "Info": "Job completed",
        "JobPriority": "Normal",
        "ReleaseName": "Other Process",
        "RuntimeType": "Unattended",
        "StartTime": "2021-02-03T05:00:07.183Z",
    },
    {
        "EndTime": "2021-02-03T05:25:00.643Z",
        "Info": "Job completed",
        "JobPriority": "Normal",
        "ReleaseName": "Other Process",
        "RuntimeType": "Unattended",
        "StartTime": "2021-02-03T05:00:07.183Z",
    }
  ]
```

In the first step I want to filter the JSON data to only keep information about those jobs named 'data scraping'.
What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Look for JsonPath, this should help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to filter, you should use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) :)

```
values = response['value'] #is a list
filtered = list(filter(lambda entry:entry['ReleaseName'] == 'Data scraping', values))
```

The lambda function will keep values if they evaluate to `true`